# Reading Polynomials - Alter Spacing in String

Tags: java, string

Is there a regex that converts uneven spacing into even spacing in strings (for polynomials)?

Like `"x^2     + x -3               +2x^-4"` into `"x^2 + x - 3 + 2x^-4"` (where there is single space between each of the terms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
String[] useCases = {"x^2 + 5x -3 +2x^-4",
        "x^5-4x+4x^3+4",
        "x^5- 4x+4x^3+4",
        "x^5-4x +4x^3+4",
        "x^5-4x +4x^3+ 4"
};
for(String s : useCases) {
    System.out.printf("%-22s",s);
    s = s.replaceAll("\\s*((\\d*[a-z]+\\^[+-]*\\d+)|(\\d*[a-z])|(\\d)+|([+-\\/*]))\\s*", "$1 ");
    s = s.strip();
    System.out.println("-> "+ s );
}
```

Output:

```
x^2 + 5x -3 +2x^-4    -> x^2 + 5x - 3 + 2x^-4
x^5-4x+4x^3+4         -> x^5 - 4x + 4x^3 + 4
x^5- 4x+4x^3+4        -> x^5 - 4x + 4x^3 + 4
x^5-4x +4x^3+4        -> x^5 - 4x + 4x^3 + 4
x^5-4x +4x^3+ 4       -> x^5 - 4x + 4x^3 + 4
```

Modify the code as per your needs.

Comment: Thanks, it almost works except that it is not allowing any coefficients other than 1 for the variables. For example "x^2     + 5x -3               +2x^-4" this string is separating the 3 coefficient from the variable x. Is there a way you can fix that in the regex.

Comment: `5x-3` is not same as `5(x-3)`. elaborate more.

Comment: I meant the first one. 5x - 3, don't worry about parentheses (at least i don't need it for my program)

Comment: changed the expression to handle more use cases.

Answer (score 0):

I broke up the regex statements for easier understanding. The first regex statement replaces multiple spaces with just a single space. The next two checks that there isn't a space preceding the +/- and adds a space. The last two regex check the opposite where if a +/- isn't followed by a space, it adds a space.

```java
str = str.replaceAll(" +", " ");
str = str.replaceAll("(?<! )[+]", " \\+");
str = str.replaceAll("(?<! )[-]", " -");
str = str.replaceAll("[+](?! )", "\\+ ");
str = str.replaceAll("[-](?! )", "- ");
```

`str.replaceAll(" +", " ");`

Comment: I think he wants `2x^-4` as a single unit.

Comment: @onkarruikar Ah i see it now i didn't notice the lack of spaces there